# How increment ++ really works and how to adapt it to exclude an invalidity?

Tags: programming-languages, c, if-statement

#### The context:

As part of a class project, I created this [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B14GJ9Df7LmqbkFmdGJBRTdyTXM/view?usp=sharing) (Original Version). It works great, had almost full grade. As I was learning new materials, I challenge myself to rewrite the original code and to implement the new stuff in it. So basically what [this new version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B14GJ9Df7LmqUk1GOU8yZi1TYmM/view?usp=sharing) (not much difference with the original - feel free to compare) does is:

1. you enter a letter c/C for circle, r/R for rectangle, and k/K for Square,
2. enter the desire measurement,
3. it accordingly calculates the perimeter and the surface,
4. as the user if he wants to continue,
5. repeat the process,
6. display (in same order) the following information when the user decides to stop:

   - total number of figures treated,
   - the larger surface,
   - the smaller circle perimeter,
   - total number of rectangle with length > 7.8,
   - total number of square treated,
   - the average length of the side of the square treated.

Notice in the execution below that 3 of the 4 characters enter are valid. So we get their surface and perimeter. However 'T' is an invalid character, but when the user decides not to continue it is still counted as part of the total figure and gives me 4 instead of 3:

```
Entrez le caractere correspondant a la figure geometrique (c,C,r,R,k,K): c
Veuillez entrer le rayon: 10
Le perimetre est de: 62.83
La surface est de: 314.16

Voulez-vous continuer ? (o/n) o
Entrez le caractere correspondant a la figure geometrique (c,C,r,R,k,K): t
Le caractere 'T' est invalide

Voulez-vous continuer ? (o/n) o
Entrez le caractere correspondant a la figure geometrique (c,C,r,R,k,K): k
Veuillez entrer le cote du carre: 5
Le perimetre est de: 20.00
La surface est de: 25.00

Voulez-vous continuer ? (o/n) o
Entrez le caractere correspondant a la figure geometrique (c,C,r,R,k,K): r
Veuillez entrer la longeur et largeur du rectangle: 10 5
Le perimetre est de: 30.00
La surface est de: 50.00

Voulez-vous continuer ? (o/n) n

Au total, on a traite 4 figure(s)
La surface la plus grande est: 314.16
Il y a 1 rectangle(s) dont la longueur depasse 7.80 metres
Le plus petit perimetre des cercles est: 62.83
Le nombre total de carre traitees : 1
Le cote moyen des carres traites est de: 5.00

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 47.514 s
Press any key to continue.
```

#### Question:

***How to adapt the increment (somFigure++) in a way that it only counts the valid characters enter by the user?***

#### Source code:

```c
 int main() {
    char figure,
         reponse;
    int valide,
        nbCarre = 0,
        somFigure = 0,
        nbGrRec = 0;
    float perimetre,
          surface,
          rayon,
          longueur,
          largeur,
          cote,
          somCarre = 0.0,
          plusGrandeSurface = 0.0,
          plusPetitPerimetreC = 5000.0;
    const float PI = 3.14159,
                GRAND_RECTANGLE = 7.8;

    do
        {


    printf("Entrez le caractere correspondant a la figure geometrique (c,C,r,R,k,K): ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    figure = toupper(getchar());
    valide = (figure == 'C') || (figure == 'R') || (figure == 'K');

    somFigure++;

    switch (figure) {

        case 'C': printf("Veuillez entrer le rayon: ");
                  scanf("%f", &rayon);
                  perimetre = 2 * PI * rayon;
                  surface = PI * rayon * rayon;
                  if (surface > plusGrandeSurface)
                    plusGrandeSurface = surface;
                  if (perimetre < plusPetitPerimetreC)
                    plusPetitPerimetreC = perimetre;
                  break;

        case 'R': printf("Veuillez entrer la longeur et largeur du rectangle: ");
                  scanf("%f%f", &longueur, &largeur);
                  perimetre = 2 * (longueur + largeur);
                  surface = longueur * largeur;
                  if (longueur > GRAND_RECTANGLE)
                        nbGrRec++;
                  if (surface > plusGrandeSurface)
                    plusGrandeSurface = surface;
                  break;


        case 'K': printf("Veuillez entrer le cote du carre: ");
                  scanf("%f", &cote);
                  perimetre = 4 * cote;
                  surface = cote * cote;
                  nbCarre++;
                  somCarre +=  cote;
                  if (surface > plusGrandeSurface)
                    plusGrandeSurface = surface;
                  break;

        default:  printf("Le caractere '%c' est invalide\n", figure);

   }  /* Fin du Switch */

   if (valide) 
        printf("Le perimetre est de: %.2f\n", perimetre),
        printf("La surface est de: %.2f\n", surface);


    printf("\nVoulez-vous continuer ? (o/n) ");
    fflush(stdin);
    reponse = getchar();
    fflush(stdin);

        }while(toupper(reponse) == 'O'); /* Fin de la boucle do....while */


    printf("\nAu total, on a traite %d figure(s)\n", somFigure);
    printf("La surface la plus grande est: %.2f\n", plusGrandeSurface);

    if (nbGrRec > 0)
    {
        printf("Il y a %d rectangle(s) dont la longueur depasse %.2f metres\n", nbGrRec, GRAND_RECTANGLE);
    }
    else
        printf("Il y a aucun rectangle traite\n");

    if (plusPetitPerimetreC != 5000.0)
    {
        printf("Le plus petit perimetre des cercles est: %.2f\n", plusPetitPerimetreC);
    }
    else
        printf("Il y a aucun cercle traite\n");

    // Fait un resumer des nombre de carrés traités si l'utilisateur decise de ne plus continuer
    if (nbCarre > 0)
    {
        printf("Le nombre total de carre traitees : %d\n", nbCarre);
        printf("Le cote moyen des carres traites est de: %.2f\n", somCarre / nbCarre);
    }
    else
        printf("Il y a aucun carre traite\n");

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if (valide) {
  somFigure++;
  printf("Le perimetre est de: %.2f\n", perimetre),
  printf("La surface est de: %.2f\n", surface);
}
```

Also note that the original code without the curly braces probably does not work as you expect. The first `printf`statement will be executed only if `valide` is true but the second one will be executed in any case. It's a good practice to always use curly braces with `if` statements to avoid errors like this.

Comment: It works, Thank you very much @Muton.
To recap: The solution was to move the 'somFigure++;' inside the if statement. So if i understood, the increment count will only start when the condition is true.

Comment: @BorisAnselme Muton did a great job of describing the problem, but the real message you should leave with is the last line of his answer.  Even if you have an `if` statement that has only one statement behind it, use curly braces.  By adopting a practice of always using them, you cannot accidentally miss where the `if` statement sub-block begins and ends (this especially is true if you indented your code differently than it is programmatically structured).

Comment: @EdwinBuck Thank you for the advice. I will put it in practice.